# Javascript: How to extend an array with a dictionary with { key: array values} without logging [Object] to console

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary

```
h =  { toys: [ { name: 'Toy 1', price: 900 } ] }
```

and an array

```
arr = []
```

How can extend arr with h
using push or something else to have

`arr.push(h)` gives `[ { toys: [ [Object] ] } ]`

Desired result is:

```
 [ { toys: [  { name: 'Toy 1', price: 900 } ]  } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> arr.push(h) gives [ { toys: [ [Object] ] } ]

This is because `console.log` somewhere does not show the deep levels of nested objects. You just need to use `console.dir` with the `depth` option. Check this out:

```
h =  { toys: [{ name: 'Toy 1', price: 900 }] };
arr = [];
arr.push(h);
console.dir(arr, { depth: null });
```

Comment: Thanks and I accepted your answer, the original question was a task that need to return a customer to orders relationship in JS function, from codesignal precisely, but I had to return the result in a function and the value was being given in the format above , now Sir, say I want to return the arr from this function , and some tests was run in the background using mocha or specs, How will I ensure it still comes out in a pure JSON format without stringify

Comment: Just like imagining all your code is wrapped in a function and you needed to return arr this time but in the same format without console.dir or any other console functions

Comment: @optimus Do you want formatted output? Just use `JSON.stringify(arr, null, '  ')` with options

Comment: I owe you a drink Sir :) but just to clarify, I hope the formatted output still returns as a parsed Object then and not just as a string , if case if typescript procedures were applied for the return type

Comment: @optimus hm,  `JSON.stringify` return just a formatted string, not an object. It is a text representation of an array or object. But to be honest, I have a difficult understanding of the task. Could you please create a new question to describe the task in detail, what input data, what expected data, and what are the difficulties of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```js
const h =  { toys: [ { name: 'Toy 1', price: 900 } ] };
const arr = [h];
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: how much is different from pushing `h` in the array? who asked the question clearly didn't get the point

Comment: I am using node version 16.3.0, My console.log still prints [ { toys: [ [Object] ] } ]
but stackoverflow console prints it the way I want, could this be an issue with node versions being used??